# Npm not able tp find File - ENOENT

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

[image: Npm not able tp find File]

Npm not able tp find File

[image: Npm error file]

Npm error file

I encountered this problem after a friend zipped the file to me. I have also tried npm init but after that error continues.

i need help on how to go about this

Comment: You have started to wrong directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently in React_Projects directory so you need to navigate to roboapp and then do npm start

In your command line

Do

```
C:\Users\Visitor\Desktop\React_Projects>cd roboapp
```

And then do

```
C:\Users\Visitor\Desktop\React_Projects\roboapp>npm start
```

Comment: @JudeObiejesi You are welcome. Please do upvote and accept the answer as verified